# GNOME Shell - display path of files in Activities window

Tags: gnome-shell

One feature that I really like of GNOME Shell is the possibility to just type the name of a file in the Activities window and have a list of matching files shown, so that you can open them.

However, only the file name is displayed, and not the path.

Questions:

1. Is there any way (setting, external plugin etc.) to also show the path?
2. If there is not, how would I go to write one? What components need to be edited? Would a GNOME Shell plugin be able to modify the activities window?

Comment: The behaviour in the more recent `gnome-shell` version is the one you want (the file name is listed and also the full path is listed underneath). This assumes the directories are indexed by `tracker`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be confusing Unity with Gnome-Shell. Gnome-Shell does not provide any file search capabilities by default and there isn't any extension that does it either, as far as I know. The only thing it does do is search in nautilus  bookmarks such as Downloads, Documents, etc and there isn't much to know about them as long as you don't have a ridiculous  amount of them.

Comment: hmmm no, I can assure you I have Gnome-Shell (FC16) and yes, I have a lot of files in there so it would be very useful to know info about it (plus it would be fun to code a plugin :P)

Comment: Debian testing here, a few versions back, so I didn't know. :D

Comment: my bad... actually, it looks like it's pulling them out of recent items. The need comes from the fact that I have several files with same name in different paths and knowing where they are would help a lot

Comment: Just as an additional info: there is a nice extension for tracker integration into GNOME Shell [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/284/tracker-search/). Works very well.